# SynchronousQueue in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, blockingqueue

I'm trying to understand the behavior of queues in `ThreadPoolExecutor`. In the below program, when I use `LinkedBlockingQueue`, I can submit only one task to the thread pool at a time. But if I replace the `LinkedBlockingQueue` with `SynchronousQueue`, I could submit all the 5 tasks to the pool at an instant. How `SynchronousQueue` differs from `LinkedBlockingQueue` in this case ?

**Java program :**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> threadPoolQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
//      SynchronousQueue<Runnable> threadPoolQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
        ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, threadPoolQueue, threadFactory);
        Runnable np;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            np = new SampleWorker("ThreadPoolWorker " + i);
            tpe.submit(np);
        }

        System.out.println(tpe.getCorePoolSize());
        System.out.println(tpe.getPoolSize());
        System.out.println(tpe.getActiveCount());

        tpe.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        tpe.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Main task finished");
    }
}

class SampleWorker implements Runnable {
    private String workerName;

    SampleWorker(String tName) {
        workerName = tName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println(this.workerName);
            }
            System.out.println(this.workerName + " finished");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591610/when-should-i-use-synchronousqueue)

Comment: @avix That explains the difference between `SynchronousQueue` and `LinkedBlockingQueue` (with a size of 1). But here I'm didn't specify any size for either of the queues. And with the `LinkedBlockingQueue` I could submit only one task at a time, whereas with the `SynchronousQueue` I could submit all the 5 tasks simultaneously. I have set to `corePoolSize` to 0 in both the cases. Will `corePoolSize` doesn't affect `SynchronousQueue` ?

Comment: @UnahD `corePoolSize` doesn't affect underlying `BlockingQueue`, it controls thread pool size of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, not `BlockingQueue` size. And, as documentation says, `SynchronousQueue` [does not have any internal capacity, not even a capacity of one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) and also `size()` [always returns zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html#size())

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you submit a task to `ThreadPoolExecutor`, it works like this :

```
if (numberOfWorkingThreads < corePoolSize) {
   startNewThreadAndRunTask();
} else if (workQueue.offer(task)) {
   if (numberOfWorkingThreads == 0) {
       startNewThreadAndRunTask();
   }
} else if (numberOfWorkingThreads < maxPoolSize)
    startNewThreadAndRunTask();
} else {
    rejectTask();
}
```

- When using `LinkedBlockingQueue` with no initial value,
  `workQueue.offer(task)` will always success, resulting only one
  thread started.
- When calling `SynchronousQueue.offer(task)`, it successes only when
  another thread is waiting to receive it. Since there is no waiting
  thread, `false` will be returned and new thread is created every
  time.